# How to check for empty of an argument passed to a function in bash

Tags: bash, variables, scope, scripting

I am implementing a `bash` shell script which takes in user inputs ( via `read`) to several variables and perform some tasks. Following is a sample code snippet

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function1(){
      read -p 'Enter Input2: ' variable2
      #more lines
      captureUserInput 'Enter Inputx: ' varibleNameAsAString
      echo "After setting up $varibleNameAsAString"
}

read -p 'Enter Input1: ' variable1

captureUserInput(){
    read -p "$1" $2
    while [ -z "$2" ]
    do
        echo "Invalid Inputs"
        read -p "$1" $2
    done
}

function1
```

How do I check whether the variable `varibleNameAsAString` passed to `captureUserInput` function is set within the function and prompt again if not set? Thanks in advance

Comment: You're already using the test-functionality `[ -z "$2" ]`, why don't use it in the function, too?

Comment: Quote `$2` in the call to `read`; if it's not a valid variable name, you want `read` to raise an error, not silently treat a bad input like `foo bar` as two separate variable names, triggering word-splitting.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is testing `$2`. `$2` is the name of the variable, **not** the variable's content.

You need to use [variable indirection](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) `${!2}`:

```
capture_input() {
    (( $# < 2 )) && return 1
    while 
        IFS= read -rp "$1" "$2"
        [[ ! ${!2} ]]
    do
        echo "Invalid input!"
    done
}
```